# In Visual Studio, is there a way to automatically convert an objects data to object creation code?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio or in a VS plugin, is there a way to automatically convert an objects data at run time to generated class initialization code? I am trying to create test data and It would be really convenient to have the ability to copy a run time objects data into object initialization code through intellisense.

If this isn't possible or has yet to be created, are there alternatives to accomplish something similar?

Answer (score 1):

[Object Exporter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OmarElabd.ObjectExporter) extension lets you export out an object while debugging in Visual Studio to C# Object Initialization Code, JSON and XML.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about C++ - this is called copy constructor and it's part of the language definition.

Comment: I wasn't aware that a copy constructor generated class instantiation code. I thought it simply copied an object.

Comment: @Robbie That's right, it doesn't generate. *It is* an instantiation code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a build-in function for this, but you can easily write one yourself if you're talking about C# with Reflections.

With C/C++ shouldn't the hexdump of the object be enough, if you just write the raw data at the position of the pointer?

Comment: I was hoping a plugin might be available.

Thanks for your response.